# Adding additional disks to HP P2000 SAS Storage

Tags: raid, vmware-esxi, hp, vmware-vsphere, storage-area-network

We have a 12 bay HP P2000 SAS Enclosure with 6 drives on RAID 5 installed. The drives are configured as 2 separate DataStores for a VMWare vSphere ESXi setup.

Now we want to add:

1. 6 additional drives
2. Configure RAID for new disks
3. Add as a separate datastore to vSphere

Are there any guides on the whole process? I Googled and found some nice ones for item 3 but not 1 & 2.

Thank you.

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

The [HP P2000 G3 manual](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?sp4ts.oid=4118559&docId=emr_na-c02254382&docLocale=en_US) and [SMU Reference Guide](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?sp4ts.oid=4118559&docId=emr_na-c02520791&docLocale=en_US) cover this quite well. The basic overview is:

- Plug the new disks in.
- Create a new Virtual Disk with the new physical disks.
- Create a volume.
- Assign it to your vSphere hosts.
- Rescan in VMware and format a VMFS volume.

For the P2000 side, there's a *"Provisioning Wizard"* in the web interface that will guide you through the process. Please refer to that section in the [SMU Reference Guide](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?sp4ts.oid=4118559&docId=emr_na-c02520791&docLocale=en_US).

Answer (score 0):

once you have inserted the Disks and used the HP SMU to configure the Vdisks and volumes, and setup your RAID a useful guide can be found here [SMU Guide](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c02520791)

on the P2000 you would need to create separate Vdisks say vd01 (RAID 5) and vd02 (RAID 5) then on each vdisk configure your volume.

depending on how you want to connect the P2000 to the ESXI servers i use iscsi cables that plug direct from the ESXI Server's H221 Host Buss Adapterto the P2000. in the vsphere client of web browser, Select your Host>configuration>storageAdapters then in the top right rescan all, this should find your new volumes with separate LUN Numbers, when you add them they should appear as separate data stores

we have it on one of our ESXI host running on an old MSA2000 Stroage array.

[image]

Vmware best practice says to have 1 LUN for 1 VMFS however.

hope that helps